# How can I use spaces in a form input's user entered value with jQuery .serializeArray and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form element and I use this (abbreviated),

```
var dataArray = $(this).serializeArray(),
    dataObj = {};

$(dataArray).each(function(i, field){
  dataObj[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

I then use that data with Ajax, sending it to a PHP page (abbreviated).

```
url: '/api/controller/name/' + dataObj['guys-name']
```

If I enter this (minus quotes),

> The lazy brown fox

It is submitting like this, which I understand because it has spaces %20,

```
The%20lazy%20brown%20fox
```

But when I use `print_r()` I get this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => thelazybrownfox
)
```

I need this so someone can enter a name in one line like smith john.  I can make two form inputs, but that is not what I want to do.

Comment: If the array data is sent correctly and PHP reads it "incorrectly", then I suspect you have processed it in some way before printing it, or the problem may be encoding. Have you tried a different encoding of the data on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

URL strings browser transform using [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). Right way 
Correct way is to use the GET or POST parameters.

```
$.post( "/api/controller/name/", { name: dataObj['guys-name'] } );
```

Or decode string "The%20lazy%20brown%20fox" from Punycode.

Comment: My API requires it to be in the URI.  Isn't that sending it as ?guys-name=smith?  I was trying to get /api/controller/name/myvalue.

Comment: Decode your Punycode on server side http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-utf8.php, https://github.com/true/php-punycode/blob/master/src/Punycode.php